# Speech Synthesis API Supported Languages

Tags: speech-synthesis

does anybody have a list on the languages which Speech Synthesis API supports?  Or a snippet of code I could run to find the different languages? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of supported voices is different for each browser/OS combination.
I wrote a jsbin showing the voices of the browser/OS on which it's run:
https://jsbin.com/ginanegoqu/edit?js,output

```
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    // Start an html table for languages details
    var text = '<table border=1><tr><th>Default<th>Language<th>Local<th>Name<th>URI</tr>';
    // Get voices; add to table markup
    function loadVoices() {
        var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        voices.forEach(function(voice, i) {
          // Add all details to table
          text += '<tr><td>' + voice.default + '<td>'
              + voice.lang + '<td>' + voice.localService
              + '<td>' + voice.name + '<td>' + voice.voiceURI;
        });
    }
    loadVoices();
    langList.innerHTML = text;
    // Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function(e) {
        loadVoices();
        langList.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: The above JSBin is "expired" and requires logging in to see properly. The MDN has a good explanation and similar live generated list - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices