# Voice Response In Tamil Language Using java-script with SpeechSynthesisUtterance?

Tags: javascript

As i'm doing voice based project for that purpose i want to return my Tamil language input in Tamil language with SpeechSynthesisUtterance i tried but i did not get the exact voice.Please anyone suggest me and let me know what i did wrong.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello,உங்கள் பதிவு செயல்முறை நிறைவடைந்தது');
    utterance.lang='ta-IN'; // for US english, en-GR for british
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `i did not get the exact voice` can you elaborate it?

Comment: Sorry For My English..Actually I Tried with some sentence in English and i replaced  'utterance.lang='en-US'' its works fine for me but when i started to use in tamli language (i.e) "utterance.lang='ta-IN'' Its not working for me it does not gives me the voice input properlly.

Comment: What do you mean by **it does not gives me the voice input properly**. Want to know what are you getting exactly. Is there any error or output in different format etc. Please mention clearly so that people here can understand it and help you.

Comment: Are you sure that Tamizh is supported. if so, then check if the lang 'ta-IN' is correct. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549950/speech-synthesis-api-supported-languages

Comment: @PrabhuThomas i don't know whether it supports tamil i tried but it doesnot pronounce properlly.

Comment: Whe you say, 'it does not pronounce properly', does that mean you can hear it speaking in Tamizh, but the pronunciation is wrong ??

Comment: yes exactly @Prabhu Thomas